SQL ParseException on UNION ALL with CTE: missing EOF at ')' near 'id_phase'
I'm working in a SQL environment (Hive dialect) and trying to combine data from multiple tables using a common table expression (CTE) and UNION ALL. The query involves multiple SELECT statements inside a CTE, each joined to several tables and returning the same set of columns.
However, I keep getting this error:

SQL Error [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 16:0 missing EOF at ')' near 'id_phase'

I've verified that:

All referenced columns exist (including id_phase)
The number and order of columns in each SELECT within the UNION ALL are identical
There are no trailing commas or mismatched parentheses
Removing inline comments and ensuring consistent aliasing doesn’t fix the issue

Below is a simplified and obfuscated version of my query that still reproduces the error. The table and column names have been changed for confidentiality, but the structure is the same.
WITH all_data AS (
  -- Phase A
  SELECT
    tA.loan_id,
    tA.snapshot_date,
    tA.phase_number AS phase_no,
    NULL AS amortization_profile_code,
    'PHASE_A' AS current_phase_type,
    rA.ref_rate_code,
    dA.margin_rate_calc,
    dA.interest_rate_calc,
    dA.rate_type_code,
    dA.interest_rate_cap
  FROM mydb.table_phaseA tA
  LEFT JOIN mydb.table_refA rA ON tA.id_phase = rA.id_phase
  LEFT JOIN mydb.table_dataA dA ON tA.id_phase = dA.id_phase

  UNION ALL

  -- Phase B
  SELECT
    tB.loan_id,
    tB.snapshot_date,
    tB.phase_number AS phase_no,
    NULL AS amortization_profile_code,
    'PHASE_B' AS current_phase_type,
    rB.ref_rate_code,
    dB.margin_rate_calc,
    dB.interest_rate_calc,
    dB.rate_type_code,
    dB.interest_rate_cap
  FROM mydb.table_phaseB tB
  LEFT JOIN mydb.table_refB rB ON tB.id_phase = rB.id_phase
  LEFT JOIN mydb.table_dataB dB ON tB.id_phase = dB.id_phase

  UNION ALL

  -- Phase C
  SELECT
    tC.loan_id,
    tC.snapshot_date,
    tC.phase_number AS phase_no,
    tC.amortization_profile_code,
    'PHASE_C' AS current_phase_type,
    rC.ref_rate_code,
    dC.margin_rate_calc,
    dC.interest_rate_calc,
    dC.rate_type_code,
    dC.interest_rate_cap
  FROM mydb.table_phaseC tC
  LEFT JOIN mydb.table_refC rC ON tC.id_phase = rC.id_phase
  LEFT JOIN mydb.table_dataC dC ON tC.id_phase = dC.id_phase
)
SELECT 
  SUM(group_count) AS total_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    COUNT(p.functional_id) AS group_count,
    ph.amortization_profile_code,
    ph.current_phase_type,
    ph.ref_rate_code,
    ph.margin_rate_calc,
    ph.interest_rate_calc,
    ph.rate_type_code,
    ph.interest_rate_cap
  FROM mydb.main_table p
  INNER JOIN all_data ph
    ON p.loan_tech_id = ph.loan_id
    AND p.snapshot_date = ph.snapshot_date
    AND p.phase_number_to_use = ph.phase_no
  WHERE
    p.snapshot_date = '2024-10-31'
    AND p.loan_status IN ('Active','Blocked','In Service','Prefinancing')
    AND p.segment_code = 'SEG001'
  GROUP BY
    p.source_code, 
    p.contract_id, 
    p.lender_party_id, 
    p.loan_status,
    p.creation_date,
    p.effective_date,
    ph.amortization_profile_code,
    ph.current_phase_type,
    ph.ref_rate_code,
    ph.margin_rate_calc,
    ph.interest_rate_calc,
    ph.rate_type_code,
    ph.interest_rate_cap
  HAVING
    SUM(p.outstanding_principal) <> 0
) subq;

What's happening?
I'm getting a parse error specifically mentioning ')' near 'id_phase'. This suggests the parser is having trouble interpreting the CTE or one of the JOIN conditions.
If I remove the UNION sections and just run one of the SELECT queries inside the CTE alone (without UNION), it works fine. The error appears only when combining them with UNION ALL.
Desired Result
I want to successfully run this query so that it aggregates counts of loans (group_count) joined with their corresponding phase data. The final result should return the total summed group_count after grouping by the columns listed.
Question
What could be causing this ParseException in Hive-like SQL when using multiple UNION ALL statements in a WITH clause? Are there any known quirks or issues (such as comment placement, invalid aliases, or special characters) that could trigger a parse error like this, and how can I resolve it?
What I've tried:

Removing the inline comments completely
Using fully qualified column names in all JOIN conditions
Ensuring the final SELECT after the CTE is directly following the CTE definition without extra characters
Changing aliases to simpler ones
Checking for hidden non-printable characters

None of these attempts resolved the issue

Are you sure this dialect supports WITH and that it's not composing it into some outer query?

Don't you GROUP BY too many columns?

can you try wrapping  parenthesis for each UNION , your error message shows around line 16, and I think that is where the second UNION starts

Start with much simpler query,  maybe just union of one column from each table, and simple select from cte without group by... then add elements, until you find where is the problem.

Bingo!! Wrapping parenthesis for each UNION fixed it but it would be really interesting to know what was happening

Awesome! some of the databases use parenthesis like () MINUS () etc , so I guessed may be its the parenthesis  @YasmineDaly
